# Flutter ARcore how to display widget in 3D?

Tags: android, flutter, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I'm trying to use this package for android: https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin

I need to show the widget in 3D like this example. However, ARcore is very poorly documented, unlike ARkit for iOS.

Is there anyway to display 3D widget on Android? Thank you

[image]